# Shorthand conversion from Result to Future in Swift?

Tags: swift, combine

I'd like to provide `Combine` counterparts to completion closures which is becoming very cumbersome. Is there a shorter way or extension that can convert the following:

```
extension MyType {
    
    func send(with request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (Result<MyResponse, MyError>) -> Void) {
        // Logic
    }
    
    func send(with request: URLRequest) -> Future<MyResponse, MyError> {
        Future<MyResponse, MyError> { promise in
            send(with: request) { result in
                switch result {
                case let .success(response):
                    promise(.success(response))
                case let .failure(error):
                    promise(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Future` method is just a wrapper to the completion closure method. I was hoping to do at least something like this:

```
Future<MyResponse, MyError> { send(with:request, completion: $0) }
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this since this will be applied in a lot of places in my library.

Comment: Ah I can, thank you.. much better!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the `completion` parameter of the first `send` overload has the type:

```
Result<MyResponse, MyError>) -> Void
```

Which is exactly the same type as `promise`, which is

```
Future<MyResponse, MyError>.Promise
```

[`Promise`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/future/promise) is just a type alias for `(Result<Output, Failure>) -> Void`.

So you can just do:

```
Future<MyResponse, MyError> { promise in
    send(with: request, completion: promise)
}
```

Comment: Wow amazing, did not know `Promise` was a type alias of `Result`!